# How should I handle all of this duplicate content?

Tags: mod-rewrite, duplicates

The site has Joomla. It has event_booking, which allows people to sign up for classes. Google indexed the class pages. Every page is the same except the date. I need to get those out of the index.

The URL's are of the form:

http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_dtregister&controller=event&task=options&Itemid=0&eventId=1377

How do I 301 redirect those to this real page that is already indexed:

http://www.example.com/register-class

Or should I fix the duplicate content some other way?

Answer (score 0):

Use `<link rel="canonical" href="REAL_URL_HERE"/>` for duplicated dynamic content.

Useful links:

- http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394
- http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

Unfortunately I cannot say if you should also use 301 redirect for such duplicated URLs or not -- the question is not clear enough on what other duplicated URLs you have.

---

**UPDATE:**
This rule will redirect (301 Permanent Redirect) all 3 URLs (only those, EXACT match) provided in comments to `http://www.example.com/register-class`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =controller=validate&task=email&no_html=1&eventId=1339 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =controller=validate&task=email&no_html=1&eventId=1332 [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =controller=validate&task=email&no_html=1&eventId=1382
RewriteRule ^rider-training-course-registration$ http://www.example.com/register-class? [NC,R=301,L]
```

This one will redirect the URL from Question to the same target URL (add it below aforementioned):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =option=com_dtregister&controller=event&task=options&Itemid=0&eventId=1377
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.example.com/register-class? [NC,R=301,L]
```

These rules need to be placed in **.htaccess** in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some tweaking may be required.

Comment: Sorry no that won't work. It's a joomla site so it'd be very hard to get a meta tag only on certain pages. Secondly many of these pages no longer exist but google refuses to de-index them. I need the 301 so that the user clicking the google link will be directed to the intended page.

Comment: @digiweb OK. Could you please provide few URLs that require fixing (as I understand they ALL need to be redirected to `example.com/register-class`). I'm asking because I need to know how exactly to build a rule and you mentioned that there are quite few of them but provided only 1 example.

Comment: The situation has changed a little so I'll give you some live url's that are causing problems today.

http://www.example.com/rider-training-course-registration?controller=validate&task=email&no_html=1&eventId=1339

http://www.example.com/rider-training-course-registration?controller=validate&task=email&no_html=1&eventId=1332

http://www.example.com/rider-training-course-registration?controller=validate&task=email&no_html=1&eventId=1382

These are non-pages that appear to have the content "True" 
They're of no use to me. Google has scores of them.